# How to generate a framework from a SwiftPM-generated XCode project?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-framework

I used SwiftPM to set up an XCode project for a framework; based on

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyThing",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyThing",
            targets: ["MyThing"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyThing",
            dependencies: [])
)
```

I ran `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and then `pod install` (based on a Podfile whose content shouldn't matter). I obtain `MyThing.xcworkspace`.

Now I figured that

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyThing.xcworkspace -scheme MyThing clean build
```

should create the `.framework` -- but it doesn't, only a binary file appears. I suspect some automatism is at work here since the source folder contains a file named `main.swift`, among others.

What do I have to do to get the framework built?
I need to script the whole process, to please no manual workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing script files and framework code in one target seems to confuse SwiftPM. Moving `main.swift` out of the source folder clears up things.

Scheme `MyThing-Package` creates all build products as specified in `Package.swift`, including the framework.

If you want to have the script files in the same XCode Workspace (for editing convenience), put them in their own target. You can even create an executable product (which won't create anything useful since an executable can't link to dynamic frameworks).

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 4.0 `swift package generate-xcodeproj` doesn't automatically generate schemes for all targets, but still makes those targets accessible from Xcode.

If creating a new scheme manually once is acceptable, you can do so and add your framework target as a scheme build target.

Otherwise, new schemes can be created programmatically with libraries like [xcodeswift/xcproj](https://github.com/xcodeswift/xcproj), which allow you to parse a newly generated Xcode project and generate a new scheme with its `XCSharedData` class.

After that new framework scheme is created you can run the build with `xcodebuild -workspace MyThing.xcworkspace -scheme MyThingFramework clean build`.

Comment: Interesting reference to that library, thanks! It seems not to be necessary here, though; sorry my self-answer came in late.